# Using `retryWhen` in http requests

Tags: http, angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I have extended `Http` class to set default headers and handle errors for all the requests inside an angular2 app, and I would like to use `retryWhen()` to retry the requests on certain errors.

On which errors should `retryWhen` retry the request and on which errors should it stop?

```
@Injectable()
export class WpHttp extends Http {

  constructor(backend: ConnectionBackend,
            defaultOptions: RequestOptions,
            private wpService: WpService) {
    super(backend, defaultOptions);
  }

   get(endpoint: string, args?: QueryArgs): Observable<Response> {

    return super.get(this.getUrl(endpoint, args), this.getOptions())

        /** retry the request after 1 second */
        .retryWhen(error => error.delay(1000))

        /** timeout 3s
        .timeout(3000 , new Error('delay exceeded'))

        .catch((err) => {
            if (err.status === 400 || err.status === 422) {
                return Observable.throw(err);
            } 
            else {
                /** Stream errors in WpService */
                this.wpService.errors.next(err);
            }
        })
        .finally(() => {

        });
   }
}
```

And should it be used for `post`, `put`, `update`, `delete` requests?

Comment: The answer highly depends on your use case and on the specific request. I think to make retrying depending on the HTTP status does not make a lot of sense, because most of the time the server will be down or the client has no internet connection. So I would rather observe `navigator.online` for example - without knowing your exact use case.

Comment: @SebastianSebald sorry for late response, the case I can think of is when the server doesn't respond in (x)s (sometimes it takes 8-9 sec) in this case retry can be useful, especially on shared hosted servers

Comment: So, I guess this answers your question ;)

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39928183/angular-2-rxjs-observable-retrywhen-filter-retry-on-error-status/41720854#41720854. It should give you some insight on how to leverage status codes to build your retry logic.